# Eliminating for loop by using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame

```
ifa_num=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]
ak_num=[0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.11]
ch_dist=['if','ak','if','if','ak']
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['if_num']=ifa_num
df['ak_num']=ka_num
df['ch_dist']=ch_dist
```

[dataframe_looks_like click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALiIk.png)

I have to insert another a column  namely

- if_ak: which will have the number from ifa_num if its ch_dist is 'if' else it will take the number from ak_num

The resultant data frame should look like

[resultant data frame after adding if_ak columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSDlP.png)

I have written a naive code using for loop I am not able to figure out how to optimize it as in data grows for loop will become inefficient.

```
li=[]    
for x in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df.loc[x,'ch_dist']=='if':
        li.append(df.loc[x,'if_num'])
    else:
        li.append(df.loc[x,'ak_num'])
df['if_ak']=li
```

Comment: kindly post data not pics. much better if everything u want to share as per data is posted in ur question, than sending readers to external links.

Comment: @sammywemmy the data is confidential not allowed to be shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code below :

```
ifa_num=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]
ak_num=[0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.11]
ch_dist=['if','ak','if','if','ak']
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['if_num']=ifa_num
df['ak_num']=ak_num
df['ch_dist']=ch_dist
```

Instead of for loop

```
df.loc[df['ch_dist'] == 'if', 'if_ak'] = df['if_num']
df.loc[df['ch_dist'] != 'if', 'if_ak'] = df['ak_num']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean mask to multiply the respective column:

```py
import pandas as pd

ifa_num=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]
ak_num=[0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.11]
ch_dist=['if','ak','if','if','ak']
df=pd.DataFrame({'if_num': ifa_num,
                 'ak_num': ak_num,
                 'ch_dist': ch_dist})

m_if = df['ch_dist'] == 'if'
df['if_ak'] = m_if * df['if_num'] + (1-m_if) * df['ak_num']

df
   if_num  ak_num ch_dist  if_ak
0     0.1    0.60      if   0.10
1     0.2    0.70      ak   0.70
2     0.3    0.80      if   0.30
3     0.4    0.90      if   0.40
4     0.5    0.11      ak   0.11
```